# What's the meaning of the /persistent/ directory in Magento themes?

Tags: magento, themes, persistent

I know it has something to do with the persistent feature of Magento, introduced in CE 1.6

But what is the in-depth meaning?
Why is Magento doubling templates?

Comment: See http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read it before. It describes what the Persistant Shopping Cart feature is and how it makes use of long-term cookies. But it does not describe, why the developers felt the urge to introduce a new directory /persistent and clone existing templates to it.

Comment: Do you get to understand why magento has clone of customer/form/registrate.phtml (Persistent/customer/form/registrate.phtml)?

Comment: The link @jürgen posted is dead. Check archive.org for an older version: https://web.archive.org/web/20120429182305/http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/

Answer (score 3):

Those are used for persistent cart functionality and yes it doubles a lot

Comment: Yes, but why is it doubling directories such as checkout and customer. What's the use of it?

Comment: when persistent cart is used then other templates are used and they have differences inside as well if you compare file by file or dir by dir. Also cart and checkout behaves bit differently

Comment: I have disabled persistent cart, but still templates under persistent/customer/form are used. What does it mean?

Comment: @AntonS that's a very ignorant comment. In Magento 1.7.0.2 and upwards (and perhaps earlier), those templates are in fact overridden completely by templates in the persistent directory, regardless of what is set in the system configuration.

Comment: @Matthew-G unfortunately I have no time to verify that for you but I guess if you completely disable the functionality the right ones are used as far as I managed to test when this question was asked.

Answer (score -5):

Indeed it's not responding to much of any of the following: flush cache, cleared (`rm -rf var/cache/*`), reindexing, flushing service provider cache (memcache), removed session files anything. And I kept getting `guest login` while I clearly reset that to **NO** Mage keeps me streaming this JS with wrong information. Cause? Yet another (100's of options of everything) solution that doesn't work and hide information from the user.

I use ArchLinux ffs, I code in Clojure... why does god punish me with a job to work this magic, black-hole OOP soup of beyond proportions :(

Comment: This is downvoted because you've submitted a question, when responses are supposed to only be answers.